# noun clauses in chain?

Tags: clauses, relative-pronouns

> The problem with this generation is they take everything for granted, their parents are never at home when needed and the little time they spend together is wasted in meaningless text messages and Facebook updates

In the sentence above, the nominal predicative of *the problem with this generation* is literally the whole sentence minus *the problem with this generation*, right?

Should I bother adding *that* before each independent clause (?) or noun. By the way what do call these type of clauses that look like independent clauses but they are not  I mean they all are connected by *and*. Are they noun clauses?

Comment: `they're parents are never at home` **their**.  `and the few time they spend together` **what little** time. `is wasted in ` is wasted **on**. Not the focus of your question, so I'm keeping this a comment.

Comment: Yes, it's a coordination of **content clauses** functioning as complement of "be" it its specifying sense. The omission of the subordinator "that" is associated with informal style, but in any case you only need it once, i,e, after the matrix verb "is". Btw, in the last clause, "the few time" does not accord with "Is wasted".

Comment: "the few time" does not accord with "Is wasted". – BillJ .I see. flatter mentioned something about it but i didn't pay attention to it . What exactly is wrong with that ? It's not correct to say time is wasted ?

Comment: It's because "is wasted" is a singular verb phrase which requires the singular phrase "the little time" as subject. In any event the noun phrase *"the few time" is ungrammatical since "few" requires a plural complement, cf. "the few time**s**.

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, you should add some *thats* but in real life, *that* is quickly dying…

For instance, I almost never - not 1% of the time, I guess - use *that* here on ESE, nor on Quora which yesterday told me 75,000 people had read my posts and yet not one - count 'em; not one - person has ever tried to corrrect me.